# How do I bind the data in an input field to another input field on Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I am working on an Angular project and I have two input fields , I want the value that is put in the first input field (field1) to show in the other input (field2) but multiplied by two . How do I go about it ? How do I bind the data and multiply the value by 2 ?

For example if 2 is entered in the first input text field , it should show 4 in the other input field.

```
         <div class="field1">
         <label for="fieldinput1"><b>
           Amounts  </b>
          <span class="dpspan">*</span>
           </label><br/>
        <input name="fieldinput1" min="0.5" max="5000" placeholder="000" type="number" height="70px" 
          required>
        </div><br/>

        <div class="field2">
           <label for="fieldinput2"><b>
                Total Income Returns </b>
             <span class="Incspan">*</span>
                </label><br/>
         <input name="fieldinput2" readonly type="text" required>
```

This is my TS file after adding [ngmodel]=input1 to the text field [image]

Comment: If you add something to the 2nd input field, do you want the 1st to change as well?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis the 2nd input field has a read only option so it's just what I put in the 1st field to display in the 2nd input field but the value multiplied by 2

Comment: Is this for `angular` or `angularjs` (or just plain javascript)? Very different situations.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis it is  angularjs (7)

Comment: change your input2  in getChange function to  $event

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="field1">
 <label for="fieldinput1"><b>
   Amounts  </b>
  <span class="dpspan">*</span>
   </label><br/>
<input name="fieldinput1" [ngModel]="input1" (ngModelChange)="getChange($event)" min="0.5" max="5000" placeholder="000" type="number" height="70px" 
  required>
</div><br/>

<div class="field2">
   <label for="fieldinput2"><b>
        Total Income Returns </b>
     <span class="Incspan">*</span>
        </label><br/>
 <input name="fieldinput2" [ngModel]="input2" readonly type="text" required>
```

in your ts file

```
  input1;
  input2;
  getChange(event){
   this.input2=event*2
  }
```

another example here

```
import { Component, OnChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="getChange($event)" placeholder="type here" type="text">
    <input [ngModel]="input2" readOnly>
  `
})
export class AppComponent    {
  name=2;
  input2=this.name*2;

  getChange(event){
    this.input2=parseInt(event)*2
  }
}
```

Comment: It throws an error  
 ERROR in src/app/investmentplan/investmentplan.component.ts(18,16): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'input1'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.input1'?

Comment: just declare input1 in your ts file

Comment: inspecting my browser shows this error Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-investmentplan', 
  templateUrl: './investmentplan.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./investmentplan.component.scss']
})
export class InvestmentplanComponent implements OnInit {
  input1;
  input2;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

Comment: here is a working demo you can compare here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gly4ft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: if you want to use ngModel you need FormsModule imported in your module

Comment: try importing FormsModule in your app.module.ts

Comment: @shashikumar thanks much when I added FormsModule to my app.module.ts it works fine .

Comment: @BlindDespair thanks it works fine . Just that when the page loads , it shows the value of input field1 on the second field and when I changed the value of variable to 0 , it shows NaN on the second field when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="field1">
  <label for="fieldinput1"><b>
      Amounts </b>
    <span class="dpspan">*</span>
  </label><br />
  <input name="fieldinput1" [(ngModel)]="data.input1" (change)="changeSecondInput()" min="0.5" max="5000"
    placeholder="000" type="number" height="70px" required>
</div><br />

<div class="field2">
  <label for="fieldinput2"><b>
      Total Income Returns </b>
    <span class="Incspan">*</span>
  </label><br />
  <input name="fieldinput2" [(ngModel)]="data.input2" readonly type="text" required>
  </div>
```

and inside ts

1.declare oblect like

```
public data={
input1:number,
input2:number
};
```

2.change function like

```
changeSecondInput(){
this.data.input2=parseInt(this.data.input1)*2
```

}

Comment: it's not working it says number is a type but used as a value