# Bind one data field to another in Angular?

Tags: angular, properties

Angular has a very nice and easy to use way of binding the value of an HTML element to a data field such as this:

```
<input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName"/>
```

so whatever I type in the text field is set to the field firstName in my Angular component, and whatever the component sets it to automatically appears on the input field on the page.

But what if I need to bind the data field to another? In this particular case, there is a backing data field as a list of strings, having each single letter of the value ("firstName" in this example) as its own string. If this were C#, I'd simply do the following:

```
private List<string> firstNameLetters { get; set; }
public string firstName
{
  get { return string.Join("", firstNameLetters); }
  set { firstnameLetters = value.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList(); }
}
```

But how can I do it in Angular? I found this question: [How do I bind the data in an input field to another input field on Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970770/how-do-i-bind-the-data-in-an-input-field-to-another-input-field-on-angular)

But that looks like insidious JavaScript trickery to me. Is there a more Angulary way to do this?

Comment: Is `firstNameLetters` going to be bound on another `input` of type text? As in you have another input with `[(ngModel)]="firstNameLetters"`?

Comment: No. It's only going to be bound to a different field in the Angular component itself. The Angular component then uses this to send data to an ASP.NET controller as a JSON object.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtakpt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, that looks quite more Angulary, thanks. I'll have to adapt that solution to my Angular code.

Comment: To get even more angularly, you should really consider reactive forms. You can then use RxJS to reactively update values based on changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `input` event to update the variable:

```
  firstNameLetters: string[] = [];

  // ...

  handleInput($event) {
    this.firstNameLetters = this.firstName.split('');
  }
```

```
  <input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName" (input)="handleInput($event)" />
```

Hopefully that helps!